# Xvfb: is some delay required running some program in new session?

Tags: linux, bash, xorg, x-server, xvfb

I have a `script.sh` which I start in Xvfb new session this way:

```
Xvfb :10 -screen 0 1000x200x24 & export DISPLAY=":10" && script.sh
```

In `script.sh` I run one c++ program and one java program. However, I sometimes got errors in one or two of them: in c++ program I got `Segmentation fault` and java program I got exception something like `awt can't get display:10`. The errors disappeared when I added in the beginning of `script.sh` the line

```
sleep 2;
```

After that I didn't get any errors. How to explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is similar to [How to launch `Xephyr` without `sleep`-ing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313234/how-to-launch-xephyr-without-sleep-ing/317271).
Your applications try to access Xvfb before it is ready. The cleanest way to solve this is to use xinit.
Run Xvfb with

```
xinit script.sh -- /usr/bin/Xvfb :10
```

(include `export DISPLAY=:10` into script.sh)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try. Can you say - if I follow your solution, can other programs (which are not in script.sh) be later started in this session?

Comment: @Pavel yes, you can run other applications with `DISPLAY=:10 otherapp`

Comment: Do you mean I can run other applications from outside that session? For examplie if in script.sh only one program - gedit. How I inside that session somehow run another program? I mean there is no terminal etc.

Comment: You can run any program from anywhere in this Xvfb session.It just needs DISPLAY to be set.

Comment: Thank you very much. But could you explain how can I from Xvfb session start another application in that XVfb session if there is only one application - gedit (text editor)? I need to know it for security reasons.

Comment: This seems to be not related to your origin question, you should create a new one. I'm not sure what you are pointing to. gedit in Xvfb is useless, as it does not provide a keyboard or monitor to interact. If security is a concern, you may use cookie authentication.

Comment: If your target is to isolate an application from your system, you can use docker. If it needs an X display, you can use [x11docker on github](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker) to run GUI applications in docker.